# update brew on mac for 10.11.6

Tags: homebrew

I tried `update brew` and got the following message:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
DrewJocham:/ DrewJocham$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
The current contents of /usr/local are bin Cellar CODEOFCONDUCT.md CONTRIBUTING.md etc identiv include join_air_data lib libexec Library LICENSE.txt mysql mysql-5.6.22-osx10.8-x86_64 opt pcsc README.md share SUPPORTERS.md .git .gitignore
DrewJocham:/ DrewJocham$ brew doctor
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- mach (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/extend/pathname.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

I have tried to remove Ruby and many other things but none seem to work.

Now I read the console and ran:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

After that I ran:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

ask me to run:
`sudo xcodebuild -license`

I accepted

Now brew is still not working. When I run `brew update` I get the following error:

`-bash: /usr/local/bin/brew: No such file or directory`

----------------Update 1-------------------

After the uninstall and attempted reinstall it say `Homebrew is already installed try to remove it first if you want to reinstall it`.

When I uninstalled it the follow files were not removed:

==> Homebrew uninstalled!
The following possible Homebrew files were not deleted:

```
/usr/local/.git/
/usr/local/.github/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/local/Cellar/
/usr/local/etc/
/usr/local/Frameworks/
/usr/local/include/
/usr/local/join_air_data/
/usr/local/lib/
/usr/local/Library/
/usr/local/man/
/usr/local/mysql -> /usr/local/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.15-osx10.7-x86_64/
/usr/local/mysql-5.6.23-osx10.8-x86_64/
/usr/local/opt/
/usr/local/share/
/usr/local/var/
```

Now I did `chmod 775 /user/local/` and even `chmod 777 /user/local/` and tried to uninstall them and still got the above error when running:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"`

when I run:
`mdfind -name brew | grep \/brew$` I get the following output:

`/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew`

Comment: So it seems the brew installer failed. Can you find it with `mdfind -name brew  | grep \/brew$` ?

Comment: Yes I did, please see update one.

Comment: Try installing Brew again. Does it output any error ? Right now it's not installed